# z-index not working as expected for multiple items

Tags: html, css, z-index

How can I get a div to appear above another div even if it appears before it in the HTML.

If you look at the example below We would need the logo div to appear at the very front.

```css
div
{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #0f0;
}

.parent
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.child
{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 70px; 
    left: 30px;
    background: #f00;
    height: 60px;
}


.child-2
{
    position: inherit;
    z-index: 6;
    top: 10px; 
    left: 30px;
    background: blue;
     height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    header background repeated image
    <div class="child-2">
      logo
    </div>
</div>

<div class="child">
  hero image
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to give `z-index` to other blocks
Just give it to logo and it will be fine.

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #0f0;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: fixed;
  top: 70px;
  left: 30px;
  background: #f00;
  height: 60px;
}

.child-2 {
  position: inherit;
  z-index: 16;
  top: 10px;
  left: 30px;
  background: blue;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  header background repeated image
  <div class="child-2">
    logo
  </div>
</div>

<div class="child">
  hero image
</div>
```